# How to get document id's in BaasBox[0.9.2] using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, baasbox

I'm new to BaasBox.
Can i have answer for how to get all the document ID's in a collection of BaasBox using javascript.?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this code and i'm able to manage with it.
Hope it may help someone.

```
BaasBox.loadCollection("Loyalties")
             .done(function(res) {
                 for (var i=0; i<res.length; i++){
                     if( res[i].email == "xyz@xyz.com")
                         console.log("result ", res[i].id);
                 }
            })
            .fail(function(error) {
              console.log("error ", error);
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been having problems doing this using the Baasbox Javascript SDK (loadCollectionWithParams()), so I use the following method in javascript using jquery:

```
var collectionname = 'mycollection';
var query = 'title = "godzilla"';
var url = 'http://localhost:9000/document/' + collectionname + '?where=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log( res );
}).fail(function(error) {
    console.log( error );
});
```

In your case, you want to filter by the email, so you can change the value of the query to something like:

```
var query = 'email = "xyz@xyz.com"';
```

Notice that for the query to work, 'title' and 'email' have to be first-level keys in your documents, in other words, they should look like:

```
{
    "title": "godzilla",
    "email": "xyz@xyz.com"
}
```

source: [Baasbox Documentation](http://www.baasbox.com/documentation/?shell#retrieve-documents)